Do not trigger pixel if url contain word page
Facebook pixel triggering two times as because there are two urls in the same page [ redirection ]. but i want facebook pixel to trigger only one time.
I tried the below code :
var add = window.location.toString();

  if (add.indexOf("page=") != -1) {

        fbq('track', "PageView");
    }

So that if there is text "page" in url, then facebook event "PageView" should not trigger.
enter image description here
but if i use above code, not even a single facebook pixel will trigger. am i using wrong code ?
below is entire code i am using :
<script>
  !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
  {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
  n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
  if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
  n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
  t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
  'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
  fbq('init', '908483260167518');
  //fbq('track', 'PageView');
  $(function() {
    if ( document.location.href.indexOf('page') > -1 ) {
      fbq('track', "PageView");
    }
  /*
  var add = window.location.toString();
  if (add.indexOf("page=") != -1) {
        fbq('track', "PageView");
    }
    */
    
});

I also tried this :
var url = window.location.href;

if (url.search("#Work") >= 0) {

    fbq('track', 'PageView');
}


your problem may be the asynchronous loading of jQuery. You don't need jQuery for a simple URL check.
remove your jQuery
// $(function() {
//    if ( document.location.href.indexOf('page') > -1 ) {
//      fbq('track', "PageView");
//    }
// }); 

and instead do the check in pure JavaScript
// Directly after fbq('init', 'YOUR_PIXEL_ID');
if (window.location.href.indexOf('page=') > -1) {
  fbq('track', 'PageView');
}


still i can see  : pixel activated 2 times


so if the url contains the word  : page, than it will not trigger the pixel right  ?

if you see the 2nd url in this : https://i.sstatic.net/eASZE.png  , it contains page text in url, so i do not want to trigger pixel if the url contains word  :  page , that is my requirement.

oh sorry here it is for not triggering with the word page if (window.location.href.indexOf('page=') === -1)
